# It is possible to change ObjectAnimator end value with the animation started?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, objectanimator

I have a object animator started, and i want to change the end value sometimes when the animation is started, but without stoping and restarting it.

How can this be achieved? I can't find any info in google.

SAMPLE:

```
XMovement = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "x", startX, endX);                
XMovement.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
XMovement.start();
```

and i want to change `endX` value in real time when the animation is started.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, are you ended up recreating ObjectAnimator every time or find the way doing it realm-time?